# In CakePHP, how can I move the database.php config file outside of the APP folder

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to prevent storing passwords and security information in code files.  I've managed to move the Security.cipherSeed and Security.salt into Config files outside the application directory with the following placed in `core.php`:

```
App::uses('PhpReader', 'Configure');
Configure::config('default', new PhpReader('/etc/');
Configure::load('config.php', 'default');
```

In the above however, I can only process key value pairs, so how do I load the database config file from a file outside the entire application?  I have tried using `require_once('/etc/database.php')` in `core.php` but it's not having the desired effect.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you are setting up CakePHP properly the database.php file shouldn't be accessible by anyone without direct access to the server. These files are included in `.gitignore` to make sure that no one commits passwords to a repository too (these files should be setup directly on the server).

Comment: Thanks @drmonkeyninja, I understand your point about `.gitignore` but my reasoning was that the person setting up the application has access to the APP parent directory, but I'd like like them not to be able to view the content of the database.php config file, so that the application refers to a file stored outside the app parent directory, e.g. in the `/etc/` folder in my case.  Is this possible?

Comment: Setting up an app without access to the database or app configuration doesn't sound all that great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a short summary:

- Create `config/<filename>.php.default`
- Add `config/<filename>.php` to .gitignore
- Use a deployment script to copy `config/<filename>.php.default` to `config/<filename>.php` when doing a deployment. This can be done [using composers events](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#scripts). Just execute a php script that will do this task for you.
- Use env vars to set your actual config config values without editing the files

This will avoid that any "personal" customized config goes into the repository but keep files with default settings in the repository. The env vars are also a pretty convenient way of setting the DB connection up for example.

Comment: Thanks @burzum, the env vars apprach sounds like what I'm looking for. Many thanks.